# Terraform Import with Nested Objects

Tags: terraform

I am using the terraform to manage my GitHub repositories within an organization. *new_repo* does not yet exist and will be created with terarform, however, *existing_repo* **does** exist. I'm having trouble importing it so that terraform plan and apply understand it's an existing resources, not a new one to be created.

Code in my `repositories.tf`

```
variable "repo_names_list" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["new_repo", "existing_repo"]
}


resource "github_repository" "repositories" {
  for_each = { for name in var.repo_names_list : name => name }

  name = each.value
  visibility = "private"
  has_projects = false
  has_issues = true
  has_downloads = false
}
```

How can I import existing_repo? I've tried a few versions of the syntax and am not getting it right :(

```
resource "github_repository" "repositories" { 
    name = "existing_repo"
}
```

`terraform import github_repository.existing_repo existing_repo`

gives `zsh: no matches found: github_repository.repositories[existing_repo]`

`terraform import github_repository.repositories existing_repo` imports succesfully, but running `terraform plan` still seems to think existing_repo is new and will fail on apply

Comment: Did you do what I advised and it still does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/import#example-import-into-resource-configured-with-for_each), it should be:

```
terraform import 'github_repository.repositories["existing_repo"]' existing_repo
```